# Error handling in Teradata Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, teradata

I am trying to develop a stored procedure within TERADATA to handle and manage exceptions.

The stored procedure should raise the error to the caller, which is an SSIS Package.

I am trying to illustrate this by creating a stored procedure for illustration only.

I have these tables:

**Table_A**:

```
- ID           INT
- ITEM_NUM     INT
- DESC         VARCHAR(20)
- CREATE_DTTM  VARCHAR(2O)
```

**Table_B**:

```
- ID           INT
- ITEM_NUM     INT
- DESC         VARCHAR(20)
- CREATE_DTTM  VARCHAR(2O)
```

I have two tables that will be inserting data from two SELECT statements.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE csTest2()
SQL SECURITY OWNER
BEGIN
    DECLARE varErrorMessage char(256);
    DECLARE varSQLState char(5);
    DECLARE varReturnCode char(5);

    DECLARE varRollbackNeededInd char(1);           /* transaction mgt */
    SET varRollbackNeededInd = 'N';

    SET varReturnCode = '00000';
    SET varErrorMessage = '';

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- USING A SINGLE HANDLER WITH MULTIPLE STATEMENTS
    -- PLANING TO CHANGE ERROR MESSAGE IN EACH STATEMENT.
    ins6: BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 

        H99:Begin
            set varSQLState = SQLSTATE;
            set varErrorMessage= 'This message should not be displayed'; -- 
        end H99;

        -- IMAGINE THAT I AM GETTING THE VALUES AS INPUT PARAMERS IN THE PROCEDURE 
        INSERT INTO "Table_A"
         (ID , ITEM_NUM, DESC, CREATE_DTTM)
         SELECT 1, '222', 'SOME DESC',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;


         H98:Begin
             set varSQLState = SQLSTATE;
             set varErrorMessage= 'This message is displayed, ITEM_NUM invalid characters';
         end H98;

        -- NOW I AM DOING A SECOND INSERT TO table b WITH INVALID DATA
        -- THE VALUE FOR THE ITEM NUMBER CONTAINS ALPHANUMERICE CHARACTERS
        INSERT INTO "Table_b"
         (ID , ITEM_NUM, DESC, CREATE_DTTM)
         SELECT 1, '333F', 'SOME DESC',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

    END ins6;

    EndTrans: BEGIN

        IF varSQLState <> '0' THEN
            SET varRollbackNeededInd = 'Y';
            SET varReturnCode = '9999';
        END IF;

        IF  varRollbackNeededInd = 'Y' THEN
            ROLLBACK;        -- ROLLBACK AND SEND ERROR TO CALLER
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE 'U0123' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'SQlState is - ' || varSQLSTATE || ' - and error is - ' || varErrorMessage;
        ELSE
            END TRANSACTION; -- COMMIT TRANSACTION

        END IF;
   END EndTrans;

END;
```

The problem that I am facing with the above stored procedure is that error message that I get is not the one that I am expecting. Since error is intentionally created in my second statement I am expecting to get: **This message is displayed, ITEM_NUM invalid characters** but I am getting **This message should not be displayed**

Now if I modify the PROCEDURE to have multiple handlers, one for each statement, I do get the correct error message, but now since I am intentionally generating the error in the first statement it does not terminate the procedure, it handles the error and sets the proper message but continues to process the next statement which I am not expecting to do this, so how can I terminate this procedure?

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE csTest2()
SQL SECURITY OWNER
BEGIN

    DECLARE varErrorMessage char(256);
    DECLARE varSQLState char(5);
    DECLARE varReturnCode char(5);

    DECLARE varRollbackNeededInd char(1);           /* transaction mgt */
    SET varRollbackNeededInd = 'N';

    SET varReturnCode = '00000';
    SET varErrorMessage = '';

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    ins6: BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 

        H99:Begin
            set varSQLState = SQLSTATE;
            set varErrorMessage= 'Error is displayed in this case because ITEM_NUM';

        -- ERROR IS PRESENT IN THIS STATEMENT AND SHOULD TERMINATE THE PROCEDURE. 
        INSERT INTO "Table_A"
         (ID , ITEM_NUM, DESC, CREATE_DTTM)
         SELECT 1, '222F', 'SOME DESC',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    END ins6;

    ins7: BEGIN      
         H98:Begin
             set varSQLState = SQLSTATE;
             set varErrorMessage= 'no error is displayed in this case';
         end H98;

        -- NO ERROR IS EXPECTED, BUT IT SHOULD NOT REACH HERE SINCE WE HAD ERROR ON FIRST STATEMENT. 
        INSERT INTO "Table_b"
         (ID , ITEM_NUM, DESC, CREATE_DTTM)
         SELECT 1, '333', 'SOME DESC',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

    END ins7;

    EndTrans: BEGIN

        IF varSQLState <> '0' THEN
            SET varRollbackNeededInd = 'Y';
            SET varReturnCode = '9999';
        END IF;

        IF  varRollbackNeededInd = 'Y' THEN
            ROLLBACK;        -- ROLLBACK AND SEND ERROR TO CALLER
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE 'U0123' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'SQlState is - ' || varSQLSTATE || ' - and error is - ' || varErrorMessage;
        ELSE
            END TRANSACTION; -- COMMIT TRANSACTION

        END IF;
   END EndTrans;

END;
```

Comment: #1: The error handler in your 1st SP is just the H99 block. #2: an error handler exits the *current* `BEGIN/END`block

Comment: I have question, so in my #2 procedure, I am trying to some how, cover all statement, and as soon an error gets triggered I would like to terminate my procedure and send the proper error message to the caller. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need a global `BEGIN/END` block and the handler must be defined after the BEGIN.